# How to keep alive the map fragment when not visible

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to avoid reinitilizing the map every time when I start it from my previous screen. I use MapFragment inside my custom Fragment. Any approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `attach/detach` for mapFragment and inflate view for map fragment only once.

Answer (score 0):

The map fragment will stay alive as long as the Activity it lives in stays alive.  As soon as your Activity is destroyed (if you've gone to another screen for a while), your map fragment is also destroyed.  There is no work around for that.

Comment: Try yo use attach/detach ; show/hide and you will see there is work, when you map will be initialized only first appearing

Comment: You don't need to add fragment more than once for your Activity in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Please see FragmentPagerAdapter source for more info what I am trying to do

Comment: You would be calling `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)` only once.  Look in your onCreate() method!